# How can I remove the empty spacing on the left side of my div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a footer for my website but this ugly left side white space keeps appearing, I've already tried things such as `overflow-x: hidden`, `margin: 0` and `padding: 0`.

Here is the footer I'm trying to create as you can see the left side has space while the right doesn't

[image]

```css
#footer{
/* border: 2px dashed #f69c55;*/
display: table;
position: fixed;

bottom: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
background-color: black;
float: left;
}


#footer a{
margin-left: 50px;
vertical-align: middle;
color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
<a>Number: 0000000</a>
<a>fax: bruh moment</a>
<a>email: smidgin@gmail.com</a>
<div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `left: 0` to the footer as well

```css
#footer{
  /* border: 2px dashed #f69c55;*/
  display: table;
  position: fixed;
  left:0;

  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}


#footer a{
  margin-left: 50px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: whitesmoke;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
  <a>Number: 0000000</a>
  <a>fax: bruh moment</a>
  <a>email: smidgin@gmail.com</a>
<div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to your styles

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```